# Why is the callback function not working while using react-flutterwave-rave on test mode?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, flutterwave

I am working with flutter wave as my payment system for a web app that i am building. I am using react, so i used react-flutterwave-rave package from npm. Everything works just fine, my problem is that after inputting the test card, the response is that `We could not charge this card. Reason: This is a test environment, only test cards can be used` and won't call the callback function to run some other code that i want to run. How can i by pass this since i am don't want to go live yet ?

Answer (score 1):

There is a test card in flutterwave documentation. Use the card itself instead of a live card if you are in test mode and everything will work just fine

Answer (score 0):

your API key is wrong, goto flutterwave and copy the public test key, then you can use the test card

Comment: My public test key wasn't wrong. The thing is that Flutterwave has test cards but I was using a live card instead thus throwing the error. I debugged it myself. Thanks for the reply